# Large white marks and curled up basil leaves

Tags: diseases, basil, discoloration

[image]I’ve grown this plant from seed indoors under grow lights. Potting mix is ProMix organic. They looked great at first but then started developing these white marks and the leaves started curling up all around the edges. I’m giving plenty of water so I don’t think that’s it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you recently change the lighting?

Comment: I turned the intensity of the lights down a little but that’s all.

Comment: Perhaps a micro nutrient deficiency in case of exhausted soil or very wrong acidity?

Comment: The soil was new from a reputable brand. I guess it could be the PH levels.

Comment: I do not think it is the soil, but over-watering.